# Confusion on subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently started learning a bit about set theory and thus is really confusing me Given a set $X=\{a,b,c\}$
And another set $Y=\{\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ is $Y\subset X$
and is $X \subset Y$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither.  $X$ is however an *element* of $Y$ in this case.  There is a distinction.

Comment: Neither ${}{}{}{}{}|}$

Comment: As an aside, the [self-learning] tag is only meant to be used for questions about the *process* and *pedagogy* of learning on your own.  It is not meant to be used for questions that you happened to be studying on your own.  Think things like "*If I am teaching myself, should I give myself tests and if so how should I get them graded for correctness?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are two sets then $A \subset B$ means the following statement is true: $$ x \in A \implies x \in B.$$

In your example, $X \not\subset Y$ because $a \in X$ but $a \notin Y.$

$Y \not\subset X$ because $\{a,b\} \in Y$ but $\{a,b\} \notin X.$

Answer (score 1):

It's neither of these. In fact the sets $X$ and $Y$
don't share a common element so $X \cap Y = \emptyset $.

The set $X$ has elements $a,b,c$.

The set $Y$ has the sets `{a,b}` and `{a,b,c}` as its elements.

So obviously $X \in Y$ is valid.
But neither of $X \subset Y$ and $Y \subset X$ are valid statements.

Answer (score 1):

Neither $Y\subset X$ nor $X\subset Y$:

- The set $Y$ is a **set** of *subsets* of $X$. Every element of $Y$ is a subset of $X$.
- The set $X$ is an **element** of $Y$. The set $Y$ is equal to $\{\{a,b\},X\}$.